# Join query not working properly for all the elements in the table

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

Here is my problem, i have two tables subjects and grades.

```
  CREATE TABLE `grades` (
  `gradesID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `studentBook` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subjectID` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grade` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `grades` (`gradesID`, `studentBook`, `subjectID`, `grade`) VALUES
(1, 1034, 'AD356', 9),
(2, 1034, 'CS102', 10),
(3, 1034, 'CS103', 9),
(4, 1034, 'CS220', 5)

CREATE TABLE `subjects` (
  `subjectID` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `espb` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number_of_classes_per_week` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number_of_practices_per_week` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `subjects`
--

INSERT INTO `subjects` (`subjectID`, `name`, `espb`, `number_of_classes_per_week`, `number_of_practices_per_week`) VALUES
('AD356', '3D modeling Maya', 10, 3, 3),
('CS101', 'Introduction to object-oriented programming', 10, 3, 4),
('CS102', 'JAVA 2', 10, 3, 4),
('CS103', 'Algorithms', 8, 3, 3),
```

I need to make Join query to find all for all the subjects number of students that tried to take the exam(no matter they passed or failed).And i need to show as a result:
subjects.subjectID,subjects.name,totall number of classes and practices for every subject, number of students that took the exam(no matter passed or failed).
So this is my attempt:

```
SELECT 
  subjects.subjectID,
  subjects.name,
  (subjects.number_of_classes_per_week+subjects.number_of_practices_per_week) AS 'Totall number of classes per week',
  COUNT(grades.subjectID) AS 'Number of students that tried to pass'
FROM 
  subjects,
  grades 
WHERE 
  subjects.subjectID = grades.subjectID AND 
  grade >= 5;
```

but i get only first subjectID his number of classes for that subject and a total number of students for all the subjects
The outcome that i would like to have is like this:

```
subjectID     name                           Totall number of classes per week                      Number of students that tried to pass
AD356    3D modeling Maya                  6              10
CS101   Introduction to object-oriented programming 7      4
CS102  'JAVA 2'                            7               5   
CS103    Algorithms                        6               4
```

Comment: please provide some sample data and expected output. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinSchneider I will edit now.Just a moment

Comment: You have an aggregate function `COUNT()` but no matching `GROUP BY`.  Add `GROUP BY 1, 2, 3` to get your query to group by the first three columns of your result set. Let us know if you still have strange results.

Comment: Please provide the indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell MySQL what to count - in other words, which field should be used as a grouping identifier to count over.

In your case, that would be the subjectID, as you want to count all the grades (with a grade above or equal to 5) for each subject.

So you need to add after your WHERE statement:

`GROUP BY subjectID`

And then you should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Your are using `count()` aggregate functions without group by, so mysql returns only one row. Try this (it may help you):

```
SELECT 
  subjects.subjectID,
  subjects.name,
  (subjects.number_of_classes_per_week+subjects.number_of_practices_per_week) AS 'Totall number of classes per week',
  COUNT(distinct grades.studentBook) AS 'Number of students that tried to pass'
FROM 
  subjects
JOIN grades ON grades.subjectID = subjects.subjectID
GROUP BY subjects.subjectID
```